# C# - Avoid getting a SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, disconnect

I was wondering if there's a way to **avoid** getting a SocketException whenever I cannot connect rather than catching the SocketException using try/catch.

I have this code which checks if a server is available of not:

```
public bool CheckServerStatus(string IP, int Port)
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(IP);

            using (Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp))
            s.Connect(IPs[0], Port);

            return true;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can't you simply do nothing in the catch statement?

Comment: According to msdn: A SocketException is thrown by the Socket and Dns classes when an error occurs with the network. So this means you can't totally avoid it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may subclass `Socket` and provide your specific implementation:

```
public class MySocket : Socket{
    //...
    public boolean TryConnect(...){
    }
}
```

You could also instead of a boolean, return a `Result` object that save the exception for error handling:

```
public class Result {
    public Exception Error { get; set; }
    public boolean Success { get{ return Error != null; } }
}
```

Comment: You can do that, but that only moves the 'problem' to another place. In that `TryConnect` method, you will still get a `SocketException` in the same situation. You just handle it at a different point.

Comment: True, but if this class is intended to be reused, you would handle it at _only_ _one_ point.

Comment: That is an advantage yes, although it's not what he is asking for as he is specifically asking to avoid the exception itself. But, depending on how many times he creates sockets this might be a cleaner way to do it indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting a `SocketException` isn't a problem; this is what the exception should be used for. Depending on the type of exception you get, you can handle them different ways. It would have been bad if you just caught `Exception` rather than the more specific `SocketException`.

Why do you want to avoid it so much? As the comments say, at some point, somewhere, code will fail if the other end of the connection is not available. Just make sure you catch that failure at the appropriate place, like you appear to be doing now.

Comment: Not necessarily. A failure may be a valid result, not an "exception". Failures could be displayed in the UI or stored. Using exceptions for flow control is a bad idea and I hate how the BCL seems to have a thing for doing this in many API's. Much better to return a result and let the user decide how to handle it.

Comment: BTW, just tested the exception vs not, 25x perf hit. May be fine in some scenarios, not so fine in others.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to accomplish this using [BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginconnect.aspx) as follows

```
int connectTimeoutMS = 1000;
IPEndPoint endPoint = GetEndPoint();
var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
_socket.BeginConnect(endPoint, (AsyncCallback)delegate { evt.Set(); }, null);
evt.WaitOne(connectTimeoutMS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve the problem in the first place by using [Ahmed approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16334617/1838048), but this simply moves the problem a lever deeper.

The main reason why there exists no such a test method is the possibility of a race condition. Just imagine you would check if such a socket is possible and before you can try to establish this socket in the next line a context switch happens (to another thread or application) that just allocates this socket for himself. Now you still get the exception and you have to check for it (by using the try-catch approach).

So this test simply adds no benefit to your code, cause you still have to be prepared for a failing of this method. And that's the reason with this test doesn't exist.