# Socket exception when disconnecting

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, udp

I'm building a small UDP chat in C# Windows forms, and I'm facing a problem with the disconnect button.
When I press the disconnect button I get a socket exception that says:
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected - when sending data

My code:

```
    private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            sckCommunication.Disconnect(true);
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
            btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


    }
```

Can someone help me understand what's the problem with the button?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use socket.close instead of disconnect.

Comment: Now I'm getting a different exception on the OperatiorCallBack method: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'. the Exception occurs on this line: int size = sckCommunication.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epRemote);

Comment: yes this is valid exception because your code is stuck on client.connect() which only will executes once you get connection. so when u close it release all the resources and the connect throws the exception. so its perfect.

Comment: Alright, it seems to be working now after handling some exceptions. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: please share what u fix to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are pressing the disconnect button before you are connected?

The Socket will throw an exception if you are trying to disconnect a not connected socket...

Try something like:

`if (sckCommunication.Connected)
    {
        sckCommunication.Disconnect(true);
    }`


    `if (!sckCommunication.Connected)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
    }`

Comment: I'm not trying to press the disconnect button without connection because the disconnect button isn't enabled until there's a connection.

Comment: This is not necessarily a Problem... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334530/c-sharp-avoid-getting-a-socketexception